# I can't get golang to recognize my get request with parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, go

I am trying to get create a simple axios get request with parameters in React to work with Go. No matter what I do, keep getting the GET URL path not found (404) error.
Here is the JS

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import axios from "axios"

class ShowLoc extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const {id} = this.props.match.params
        axios.get(`/loc/${id}`)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                Specific Location
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ShowLoc
```

And here are the relevant parts of my server.go file. I am using gorilla/mux to recognize the parameters

```
func main() {

    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
    http.Handle("/", fs)

    bs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))
    http.Handle("/public/", http.StripPrefix("/public/", bs))

    http.HandleFunc("/show", show)
    http.HandleFunc("/db", getDB)

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/loc/{id}", getLoc)

    log.Println("Listening 3000")
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func getLoc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != "GET" {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(405), http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }
    id := r
    fmt.Println("URL")
    fmt.Println(id)
}
```

I never hit my getLoc function since my get request is not found. What should I do get the params from my get request?

Comment: I dont know about anxios library but shouldn't be a place you set the port and address of server ?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used your mux router. Since you passed in `nil` to `ListenAndServe`, it's using the default router, which has all of your other handlers attached. Instead, register all your handlers with your mux router and then pass it as the second argument to `ListenAndServe`.

```
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
    r.Handle("/", fs)

    bs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))
    r.Handle("/public/", http.StripPrefix("/public/", bs))

    r.HandleFunc("/show", show)
    r.HandleFunc("/db", getDB)

    r.HandleFunc("/loc/{id}", getLoc)

    log.Println("Listening 3000")
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":3000", r); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func getLoc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != "GET" {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(405), http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }

    id := r
    fmt.Println("URL")
    fmt.Println(id)
}
```

Comment: The issue is that if I do it that way, then the bundle.js file in my public directory is now not found. I'm trying to do react with a go backend. I need to be able to serve both by static html and JavaScript file to the '/' web adress, which I can't seem to do without http default router